# A smarter function to decide if C is an exact cover of S?

Tags: python, np-complete

The code works so far, but all these functions of split, new-list, and map just make it harder. Is there a mixture of set comparisons/differences to be able to do the same function that my code is doing?

Edit: All these functions such as new_list is intended to prepare the list of sets in C to be able to pass it through a loop. The loop makes sure that

1.All elements in s exist in c.

2.The 2nd part make sure there is no repeating elements in the solution. (`eg. if len(c) == len(set(new_list)` *I think I just found a semantic bug here.*

3.Use `set(new_list) == set(s)` to make sure that both sets are equal no matter what order.

```
import re

s = [2,4,8]
c = [[2], [4], [2, 4]]

new_list = (re.sub("[^0-9,]", "", str(c)))
new_list = new_list.split(',')
new_list = list(map(str, new_list))
if ('') in new_list:
    del new_list[new_list.index('')]
new_list = list(map(int, new_list))


if all(elem in new_list for elem in s):
    if len(c) == len(set(new_list)):
        if set(new_list) == set(s):
            print('This is a Yes solution')
else:
            print('This is a No solution')
```

Comment: It would help if you clearly explain what all the new_list regex stuff is trying to achieve.

Comment: That `new_list` thing is bizarre. Were you just trying to flatten `c`? There are much better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing way too much work.

1. Flattening is *much* more easily done with a list comprehension.
2. You can just compare set equality, don't need to do the `all elem` check separately since it's already guaranteed if the sets are equal.

---

```
def exact_cover(s, c):
    c_flat = [item for sub in c for item in sub]
    c_set = set(c_flat)
    return len(c_set) == len(c_flat) and c_set == set(s)
```